# jQuery script does not load in Tumblr theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I wanted to use Jquery script for my tumblr theme, but it doesn't works.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/jgemkyt9x/jquery.photoset-grid.min.js"></script>


            <script>
                $('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid();
            </script>

            {Block:Posts}
            {block:Photoset}
            <div class="photoset">
                <div class="photoset-grid" data-layout="{PhotosetLayout}">
                    {block:Photos}
                     <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" {block:Caption}alt="{Caption}"{/block:Caption} />
                    {/block:Photos}
                </div>

                {block:Caption}
                {Caption}
                {/block:Caption}
            </div>
            {/block:Photoset}
            {/Block:Posts}     
    </body>     
</html>
```

It was basically copy pasted from this site: http://buildthemes.tumblr.com/post/47574959793/responsive-tumblr-photosets-with-jquery-photoset-grid

but it doesn't works, script doesn't seems to be loaded, i think. Perhaps i put those script tags in wrong place?

Comment: wrap code in a [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Questions without code aren't future-proof. How someone else will profit from this question in the future if the links break? **Please put your *relevant* code directly in the question.**

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on what Charlie said (since you say you're a beginner at this).

The way you have it written right now, your code says: "Find all the elements that have the `photoset-grid` class, and do the `photosetGrid()` function with them."  The trouble is that when this line of code runs, the browser doesn't *know* of any elements with the `photoset-grid` class--in fact, it doesn't know about any of the body elements at all, because the browser hasn't gotten to them yet while reading the page.

(Your code doesn't give an error, though, because it says "do this to *all* of the `.photoset-grid` elements"--and this runs successfully even if there *aren't* any elements of that type, since it can still perform the operation on all zero of them.)

Instead, replace what's in between your final set of `<script></script>` tags with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid();
});
```

What this says is: "Once you've loaded in the page structure and set up the [DOM (Document Object Model)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction), then find all of the `.photoset-grid` elements and do the `photosetGrid()` function with them."